# Help me understand question related to HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

Im given a task which i am a little confused to understand. Here is the question statement:

---

The following program should read a file and store all its tokens in a member variable.
Your task is to write a single method that returns the number of items in tokenMap, the average length (as double value) of the elements in tokenMap, and the number of tokens starting with character "a".

---

Here the tokenMap is an object of type `HashMap<String, Integer>`;

I do have some idea about HashMap but what i want to know the "key value" for HashMap required is a single character or the whole word?? that i should store in tokenMap.

Also how can i compute the average length?

Comment: @duffymo: homework is a meta tag and thus discouraged

Comment: @Falmarri, actually I believe the [homework] tag is an exception to that rule.  (However, I agree that it should be discouraged)

Comment: It doesn't have to be a meta tag, but the only reason people would reasonably want it added to a question is so they can follow/ignore those questions, in which case it's basically being used as a meta tag.  Anyone that actually gets to reading the question obviously knows it's homework, so the tag doesn't provide any benefit.

Comment: As there is some debate over the homework tag, I went ahead and added it.  There are several hundred pages of questions which use this tag, and this question is definitely applicable.  If, at some point, it is determined that we shouldn't use it, they call all be removed easily enough.

Comment: the homework tag also serves as a good warning to possible answerers "don't do this person's homework for them"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to use the entire word as the key.

The average length of tokens can be computed by summing the lengths of each token and dividing by the number of tokens.

In Java, you can find the number of tokens in the HashMap by tokenMap.size().

You can write loops that visit each member of the map like this:

```
  for(String t: tokenMap.values()){
     //t is a token
  }
```

and if you look up String in the Java API docs you will see that it is easy to find the length of a String.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the average length of the items in a hash map, you'll have to iterate over them all and count the length and calculate the average.

As for your other question about what to use for a key, how are we supposed to know? A hashmap can use practically any* value for a key.

*The value must be hashable, which is defined differently for different languages.

Comment: Might want to use "object" in place of "value" to avoid some inevitable confusion, especially with people that just read *"the value must be hashable...."*

Comment: @Mark: Good point, but I'll leave it the way it is since it's the author's words and your comment makes a good clarification point.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the question closely, it seems that you have to read a file, extract each word and use it as the key value, and store the length of each key as the integer:

```
an example line
```

leads to a HashMap like this

```
an : 2
example : 7
line : 4
```

After you've built your map (made of keys mapping to entries, or seemingly elements in the question), you'll need to run some statistics over it to find

1. the number of keys (look at HashMap)
2. the average length of all keys (again, simple enough)
3. the number beginning with "a" (just look at the String)

Then make a value object containing these values and return it from the method that does the statistics.

I know I've given more information that you require, but someone else may benefit from a little extra help.

Answer (score 0):

Guys there is some confusion. Im not asking for a solution. Im just confused for one thing.
For the time being, im gonna use String type as the key type.

The only confusion i have is once i read the file line by line, should i split it based upon words or based upon each character. So that the key value should be a single character type string or a String of whole word.

If you can go through the question statement, what do you suggest. That's all im asking.

Answer (score 0):

> should i split it based upon words or
>   based upon each character

The requirement is to make tokens, so you should split them based on words. Each word becomes a unique String key. It would make sense for the value to be the count of each token.

If the file you are reading has these three lines:

```
int alpha;
int beta;
float delta;
```

Then you should have something like

```
<"int", 2>
<";", 3>
<"alpha", 1>
<"beta", 1>
<"float", 1>
<"delta", 1>
```

(The semicolon may or may not be considered a token.) 
Your average length would be ( 3x2 + 3x1 + 5 + 4 + 5 + 5) / 6.
Your length of tokens starting with "a" would be 5.0.

Look elsewhere on this forum for keySet and you should be good to go.